# Cheat of / cheat out of

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

> The engineer, in collusion with the contractor, cheated the government of a lot of money.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct. The reason to ask this question is that the phrase given [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cheat+out+of) is *cheated out of*  but [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cheated-of-or-cheated-out-of.2575736/) people have mixed opinions, so what's the correct form ?

Answer (score 1):

"Cheat of" does not sound entirely natural to me.  The idiomatic expression is "cheat *out* of".  "Cheat of" is certainly possible in some dialects, but I couldn't tell you which ones.

Otherwise, the sentence is fine but could be better written:

> The engineer *colluded with* the contractor to cheat the government out of a lot of money.

Additionally, the phrase, "a lot of money" is fine in informal conversation, but probably would not be used in something like a newspaper.  A journalist would either state the amount ("over a million dollars", etc.) or qualify by explaining why they don't know ("a substantial amount of money, but the police are still investigating the full extent of the fraud").